# What does ^ mean in a security symbol?

Tags: equities

I see `^` is in a symbol like this. In general, what does `^` mean in a security symbol? Thanks.

[https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/ago^b](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/ago%5Eb)

All the symbols with `^` are listed below.

```
AAIC^B
AAIC^C
ABR^A
ABR^B
ABR^C
ABR^D
ACP^A
ACR^C
ACR^D
AEL^A
AEL^B
AGM^C
AGM^D
AGM^E
AGM^F
AGM^G
AGO^B
AGO^E
AGO^F
AHH^A
AHL^C
AHL^D
AHL^E
AHT^D
AHT^F
AHT^G
AHT^H
AHT^I
AIG^A
AKO/A
AKO/B
AL^A
ALIN^A
ALIN^B
ALIN^E
ALL^B
ALL^G
ALL^H
ALL^I
ALLY^A
ALP^Q
ALTG^A
AMH^E
AMH^F
AMH^G
AMH^H
APO^A
APO^B
APTV^A
ARES^A
ARGO^A
ARR^C
ASB^D
ASB^E
ASB^F
ATCO^D
ATCO^E
ATCO^G
ATCO^H
ATCO^I
ATH^A
ATH^B
ATH^C
ATH^D
AVTR^A
AXS^E
BAC^B
BAC^E
BAC^K
BAC^L
BAC^M
BAC^N
BAC^O
BAC^P
BANC^E
BC^A
BC^B
BC^C
BEP^A
BF/A
BF/B
BFS^D
BFS^E
BHR^B
BHR^D
BIO/B
BIP^A
BIP^B
BML^G
BML^H
BML^J
BML^L
BOH^A
BRK/A
BRK/B
BSX^A
BW^A
BXS^A
C^J
C^K
C^N
CAI^A
CAI^B
CBB^B
CDR^B
CDR^C
CEQP^
CFG^D
CFG^E
CFR^B
CHMI^A
CHMI^B
CIM^A
CIM^B
CIM^C
CIM^D
CIO^A
CIT^B
CLNY^G
CLNY^H
CLNY^I
CLNY^J
CLVT^A
CMO^E
CMRE^B
CMRE^C
CMRE^D
CMRE^E
CMS^B
CNO^A
CNP^B
CODI^A
CODI^B
CODI^C
COF^G
COF^H
COF^I
COF^J
COF^K
COF^L
CORR^A
CRD/A
CRD/B
CSR^C
CTA^A
CTA^B
CUBI^C
CUBI^D
CUBI^E
CUBI^F
DCP^B
DCP^C
DHR^A
DHR^B
DLNG^A
DLNG^B
DLR^J
DLR^K
DLR^L
DRH^A
DS^B
DS^C
DS^D
DSX^B
DTLA^
DUK^A
DX^C
ECC           
ECOM          
EFC^A
ENR^A
EP^C
EPR^C
EPR^E
EPR^G
EQC^D
EQH^A
EQH^C
ET^C
ET^D
ET^E
ETI^
ETX           
F^B
F^C
FEI           
FHN^A
FHN^B
FHN^C
FHN^D
FHN^E
FHN^F
FNB^E
FPI^B
FRC^H
FRC^I
FRC^J
FRC^K
FRC^L
FRT^C
FTAI^A
FTAI^B
FTAI^C
FTV^A
GAB^G
GAB^H
GAB^J
GAB^K
GAM^B
GDL^C
GDV^G
GDV^H
GGT^E
GGT^G
GGZ^A
GL^C
GLOG^A
GLOP^A
GLOP^B
GLOP^C
GLP^A
GLP^B
GMRE^A
GNE^A
GNL^A
GNL^B
GNT^A
GS^A
GS^C
GS^D
GS^J
GS^K
GSL^B
GUT^A
GUT^C
HEI/A
HFRO^A
HIG^G
HL^B
HMLP^A
HT^C
HT^D
HT^E
HVT/A
IIPR^A
INN^D
INN^E
INSW^A
IVR^B
IVR^C
JPM^C
JPM^D
JPM^J
JPM^K
JPM^L
JW/A
JW/B
KEY^I
KEY^J
KEY^K
KIM^L
KIM^M
KKR^B
KKR^C
KREF^A
KSU^
LFT^A
LXP^C
MAA^I
MER^K
MET^A
MET^E
MET^F
MFA^B
MFA^C
MH^A
MH^C
MH^D
MITT^A
MITT^B
MITT^C
MNR^C
MS^A
MS^E
MS^F
MS^I
MS^K
MS^L
MTL^
NCV^A
NCZ^A
NEE^K
NEE^N
NEE^O
NEE^P
NEE^Q
NGL^B
NGL^C
NHF^A
NI^B
NLY^F
NLY^G
NLY^I
NM^G
NM^H
NMK^B
NMK^C
NNN^F
NREF^A
NRZ^A
NRZ^B
NRZ^C
NS^A
NS^B
NS^C
NSA^A
NYCB^A
NYCB^U
OAK^A
OAK^B
OFG^D
OPP^A
PBI^B
PEB^C
PEB^D
PEB^E
PEB^F
PEB^G
PEI^B
PEI^C
PEI^D
PMT^A
PMT^B
PNC^P
PRE^J
PRIF^A
PRIF^D
PRIF^E
PRIF^F
PRIF^G
PRIF^H
PSA^C
PSA^D
PSA^E
PSA^F
PSA^G
PSA^H
PSA^I
PSA^J
PSA^K
PSA^L
PSA^M
PSA^N
PSA^O
PSA^P
PSB^W
PSB^X
PSB^Y
PSB^Z
PUK^
PUK^A
QTS^A
QTS^B
RC^B
RC^C
RC^D
RC^E
RDS/B
REXR^A
REXR^B
REXR^C
RF^B
RF^C
RF^E
RLJ^A
RMPL^
RNR^E
RNR^F
RPT^D
RY^T
SAND          
SB^C
SB^D
SCE^G
SCE^H
SCE^J
SCE^K
SCE^L
SCHW^D
SCHW^J
SF^A
SF^B
SF^C
SHO^F
SHO^H
SITC^A
SLG^I
SNV^D
SNV^E
SPE^B
SPG^J
SPLP^A
SR^A
SRC^A
SRE^B
SRG^A
STAR          
STAR^D
STAR^G
STAR^I
STL^A
STT^D
STT^G
STZ/B
SYF^A
T^A
T^C
TDS^U
TFC^I
TFC^O
TFC^R
TGH^A
TGP^A
TGP^B
TNP^D
TNP^E
TNP^F
TRTN^A
TRTN^B
TRTN^C
TRTN^D
TRTX^C
TWO^A
TWO^B
TWO^C
TY^
UBP^H
UBP^K
UMH^C
UMH^D
USB^A
USB^H
USB^M
USB^P
USB^Q
USB^R
VER^F
VNO^K
VNO^L
VNO^M
VNO^N
VOYA^B
WBS^F
WCC^A
WFC^A
WFC^C
WFC^L
WFC^O
WFC^Q
WFC^R
WFC^X
WFC^Y
WFC^Z
WPG^H
WPG^I
WRB^E
WRB^F
WRB^G
WRB^H
WSO/B
XFLT^A
BCV^A
BRG^C
BRG^D
BWL/A
ECF^A
GGN^B
GGO^A
GLU^A
GLU^B
HLM^
HWM^
PCG^A
PCG^B
PCG^C
PCG^E
PCG^G
PCG^H
PLYM^A
RHE^A
YCBD^A
```

Comment: FWIW ago^b seems to be the same as ago.prb It seems to be a bond, while ago is a stock. They are having to invent a different symbol to distinguish this strange thing from the stock. https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ago.prb/company-profile https://assuredguaranty.com/investor-information/by-security/debt/678-bonds-ago-prb/

Comment: It seems that ^ (and also . ) is being used for punctuation/separation rather than having any meaning in itself. Would like to see other examples.

Comment: @noob2 I've posted all the symbols with `^`.

Comment: I checked some such symbols. It seems that symbols with `^` don't have any price info. Can I assume that this is the case for all such symbols?

Answer (score 2):

XXX^A or XXX^B or XXX^B corresponds to a [Preferred stock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_stock) ticker. For example, if you take the stock Citigroup in your list (quoted C US on Bloomberg and C on [the nasdaq website](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/c), it has the following different preferred shares on the market (see your list) :

- C^J
- C^K
- C^N

I invite you to check the differences on their respective page on the Nasdaq website.

To sum up, it is just a way of referencing preferred shares of a company.

Hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Can the price of AGO^B be found on websites like yahoo finance or tradingview?